# Word for something that has been developed to a high degree

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word (noun, preferably) for something, e.g. an idea, or technology, or any other concept that has been worked on (probably by many different sources) and evolved/developed to the point that it's now very advanced.

e.g.

"In the last 20 years or so, the Internet has become a XXXX"

Comment: There is the term *mature technology*, but that carries the implication that little more improvement is likely, or indeed, possible.

Comment: 'The finished article' is probably too strong a claim.

Answer (score 5):

How about "***[refined](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refined)***"?

> 1.2 Developed or improved so as to be precise or subtle.

Comment: I would never say a refined technology....

Answer (score 1):

I like using [*mature*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mature) to describe something that is no longer being constructed or grown the way it was at first, although there may continue to be incremental changes over time.

> Having completed natural growth and development

In my work developing software systems, once a module is considered mature, it is unlikely to undergo significant design changes, because the effort to redesign and change it would amount to a complete rebuild.

Comment: Sure, mature is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Why not *honed*?

> hone: refine or perfect (something) over a period of time.

Also valid is *iterated* or *iterated upon*, as that implies many small changes over a longer time period. This does not directly imply being advanced, however. A sentence using both:

> After being **iterated upon** for twenty years, the Internet has become a **honed** informational tool.

Comment: honed is sharpened

Comment: I wrote the relevant definition in my answer. That definition is used commonly, such as when one "hones" their skills.

Answer (score -2):

This idea is *fully fleshed out*.

This technology is *mature*.

Answer (score -2):

ingrained - firmly fixed or established; difficult to change.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ingrained

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer seems purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.